# Write requests to inventory_quantity and inventory_quantity_adjustment are no longer supported. Please use the Inventory Levels API

Tags: json, shopify, shopify-app

I know Shopify is depreciating the option to update inventory level using `admin/variants/13889269727345.json`. This method has worked for all my stores to update inventory until my recent store.Some products I can still update using the variants option and some products it will get the error 422 Unprocessable Entity. The site does not have locations enabled so why would it be complaining about using the Inventory levels API

```
{
    "errors": {
        "base": [
            "Write requests to inventory_quantity and inventory_quantity_adjustment are no longer supported. Please use the Inventory Levels API."
        ]
    }
}
```

Here is sample of what im sending to the server

```
{
    "variant": {
        "id": 13889269727345,
        "inventory_quantity": 5
    }
}
```

I cant seem to find a solution to my problem because some will work and some not and cant seem to find what causing the issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your new friends are here for you to use:

- https://help.shopify.com/en/api/reference/inventory/inventoryitem
- https://help.shopify.com/en/api/reference/inventory/inventorylevel
- https://help.shopify.com/en/api/reference/inventory/location